# Associating to every line a vector in that line in an algebraic way

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Let $X$ be a complex variety and $\mathscr E$ a locally free sheaf on $X$. Consider the fiber bundles
$$
\mathbb P(\mathscr E) \overset{def}= \mathrm{Proj}(\mathrm{Sym}(\mathscr E)), \quad \mathbb A(\mathscr E) = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathrm{Sym}(\mathscr E)). 
$$
There is a canonical rational map $f : \mathbb A(\mathscr E) \dashrightarrow \mathbb P(\mathscr E)$ sending which can be seen to be the projection $\mathbb A^n \backslash \{0\} \to \mathbb P^{n-1}$ on each fiber. Let $U(\mathscr E) \subseteq \mathbb A(\mathscr E)$ be the maximal open subset on which $f$ is defined as a map (e.g. not a rational map) ; in terms of varieties, $U(\mathscr E)$ is the complement of the image of the zero sections of $\mathbb A(\mathscr E) \to X$.

My question : Does the map $U(\mathscr E) \to \mathbb P(\mathscr E)$ admit a global section? In other words, is there an algebraic way to associate to every line in $\mathscr E$ a vector in that line?

I have a feeling this has to something to do with orientability, but I am not quite sure. The "real" picture I have in mind is $X$ being a point and $\mathscr E$ equal to $\mathbb R^3$, where this section is a half-sphere centered at the origin. However, even there I encounter issues because "half the sphere" is not an algebraic variety. I'm not convinced this result is true, but if it is, it would help me construct some maps over such vector/projective bundles.

Comment: Can you do this when $X$ is a point? You can start by considering the case where $\mathscr E$, which is in this situation is just a vector space, is of dimension $2$.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez : No, I can't. If I did I would have shown my work! I was actually hoping for a counter example but proving such a map wouldn't exist has two disadvantages : seems extremely hard to prove and doesn't make my work easier. I was hoping that someone once thought of this since it sounds like a relatively natural question.

Comment: @Mariano : The two dimensional case reminds me of stereographic projection, I just can't seem to work out the details.

Comment: In what way looking what a regular map $f:P^1\to A^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ such that $f(L)\in L$ for all lines $L\in P^1$ looks like is difficult? Have you actually tried? Such a map, when restricted to the usual two open sets that cover $P^1$ is given by some polynomials. I suggest you write down exactly what this means.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez : When you put it that way, it sounds more feasible. I guess I was motivated in the wrong direction! Thanks..